# XPATH EXPRESSION: removing a node in between

Tags: c#, xpath

I have this xml file:

```
  <Item Text="Reports" Navigateurl ="Reports/Default.aspx" Select="true">
  <Group>
    <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/Default.aspx" Select="true">
      <Group>
        <Item Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerList.aspx" 
            Select="true"   />
        <Item Text="Customer Products" 
         NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomersProducts.aspx" Select="true" />
        <Item Text="Customer Measurements" 
        NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerLocationMeasurements.aspx" Select="true"  />
        <Item Text="Customer Groups" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerGroups.aspx" 
         Select="true"/>
        <Item Text="Customer Outages" NavigateUrl="Reports/Customers/CustomerOutages.aspx" 
         Select="true" />
      </Group>
    </Item>
    <Item Text="Rules" NavigateUrl="Reports/Rules/Default.aspx" Select="true" >
      <Group>
        <Item Text="Customer Product Rules" 
         NavigateUrl="Reports/Rules/CustomerProducts.aspx" Select="true"/>
        <Item Text="Customer Product Rules Event Limits" 
          NavigateUrl="Reports/Rules/CustomerProductEventLimits.aspx" Select="true" />
        <Item Text="Customer Product  Rules Curtailable Days/Hours" 
         NavigateUrl="Reports/Rules/CustomerProductCurtailableDaysHours.aspx" 
          Select="true"  />
      </Group>
    </Item>
     </Group>
  </Item>
```

SO, when I use this XPATH Expression,

```
          XmlDataSource XmlDataSource1 = new XmlDataSource();
        XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "~/Menu.xml";
        XmlDataSource1.XPath = "//Item[@Text ='Reports']/Group/Item                  
                                  [@Select='true']       
        XmlDataSource1.DataBind();
        SiteMap1.DataSource = XmlDataSource1;
```

I get this output:

```
         Customers
            Group
               Customer Pages
          Rules
             Group
               Rules Pages
```

But I dont want the Group tag to be shown in the output. Can u please let me know how this can be achieved?

Comment: So, what *do* you want to be shown?

Comment: I just want the group element not to appear in the output

Answer (score 1):

**XPath is a *query* language for selecting nodes or extracting other data from an XML document. As such it cannot modify the structure of a document -- such as delete a node**.

Such kind of processing -- called transformation, can be easily done with XSLT and (not so easily) with XQuery.

Comment: Can I use LINQ to XML in this case?

Comment: And i dont want to actually remove it but can i write an expression whihc gets only item elements from the xml ignoring group elements

Comment: @Nishanth: No, if you select an `item` element, it continues to have a `group` child. You can't "delete" the child with XPath.